# Explode to Array

Tags: bash, shell, replace, explode

I put together this shell script to do two things:

1. Change the delimiters in a data file ('::' to ',' in this case)
2. Select the columns and I want and append them to a new file

It works but I want a better way to do this.  I specifically want to find an alternative method for exploding each line into an array.  Using command line arguments doesn't seem like the way to go.  ANY COMMENTS ARE WELCOME.

```
    # Takes :: separated file as 1st parameters
    SOURCE=$1

    # create csv target file
    TARGET=${SOURCE/dat/csv}
    touch $TARGET

    echo #userId,itemId > $TARGET

    IFS=","
    while read LINE
    do
        # Replaces all matches of :: with a ,
        CSV_LINE=${LINE//::/,}
        set -- $CSV_LINE
        echo "$1,$2" >> $TARGET
    done < $SOURCE
```

Comment: There has got to be a better title -- please update your title so it is relevant. (-1 for now, for afore mentioned reason, but that can easily be amended later.)

Comment: Place the redirection to `$TARGET` outside the loop, probably as `> $TARGET`.  You can then lose the `touch` before the loop.  Your title line needs to include quotes (`echo "#userID,itemId"`) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `set`, you can use an array:

```
arr=($CSV_LINE)
echo "${arr[0]},${arr[1]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following would print columns 1 and 2 from `infile.dat`. Replace with
a comma-separated list of the numbered columns you do want.

```
awk 'BEGIN { IFS='::'; OFS=","; } { print $1, $2 }' infile.dat > infile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl probably has a 1 liner to do it.

Awk can probably do it easily too.

My first reaction is a combination of awk and sed:

- Sed to convert the delimiters
- Awk to process specific columns

```
cat inputfile | sed -e 's/::/,/g' | awk -F, '{print $1, $2}'
# Or to avoid a UUOC award (and prolong the life of your keyboard by 3 characters
sed -e 's/::/,/g' inputfile | awk -F, '{print $1, $2}'
```

Comment: Fair comment - never knew I could get an award for it though ;-)

Comment: I'll have to find tutorials on sed and awk.  Thanks for the example.

Comment: That removes the comma. Set `OFS = FS` in a `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is indeed the right tool for the job here, it's a simple one-liner.

```
$ cat test.in
a::b::c
d::e::f
g::h::i
$ awk -F:: -v OFS=, '{$1=$1;print;print $2,$3 >> "altfile"}' test.in
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
$ cat altfile
b,c
e,f
h,i
$
```